# What do Chinese students do with the lists of new characters in 语文 textbooks?

Tags: learning-methods, chinese

In my grade-3 语文 textbooks, we find lists of new characters which appear in the accompanying essay, such as the following:

> [image: photo of 语文 textbook]

I'm curious as to what what Chinese students actually do with this.  I assume they're practiced, but beyond that I'm not sure.  (I'm also unsure as to why there are two distinct but overlapping lists of characters.)

**Question**: What do Chinese students do with the lists of new characters in 语文 textbooks?

When I encounter them, I just acknowledge them and not much else.

Answer (score 2):

Students recopy the characters in their notebooks, following specific rules for stroke order. It's a good idea to recopy each characters several times and to pronounce them out loud at the same time (along with the translation) to help with memorization.

Answer (score -1):

Usually one is the requirement of read, one is the requirement of write. They are listed as a guideline, showing the knowledge the students should gain.